# can somebody recommend a book in a group theory.

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups, abelian-groups, symmetric-groups

can somebody recommend a book in a group theory. that include just questions and their answers. $without$ $theory!$

Comment: Hmm, a book on group $theory$ without the $theory$.

Comment: Schaum series on group theory have maximum solved examples, trivial to complex. Absolutely great for beginners. Also this is of help to you http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184338/book-with-lot-of-examples-on-abstract-algebra-and-topology

Comment: yes, i just need to practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommended two books. First, if you are looking elementary questions, then you should look at this "A Course on Group Theory " by John Rose. Second, if you are looking advanced questions, then you should look at "Problems in Group Theory" by John Dixion.

Answer (score 4):

If you just need practice, I wrote a set of group theory exercises as extra exercises for an algebra course recently. These can be found at http://pure.au.dk/portal/files/56984875/exercises.pdf
There are no solutions in that set though (but most will either have been asked here or if they have not, people will almost certainly be able to provide help if you ask about them).

Comment: I have taken a look at this. It is an amazing collection. I have made two comments. 1. In exercise 10, you can use finitely generated group instead of finite group. 2.In exercise 12, It is sufficient if one of maximal subgroup is a normal subgroup.

Comment: @Babgen Thank you. The students in the course they were made for do not get introduced to the concept of being finitely generated, so I decided to focus mainly on finite groups, but if I do expand the exercises further, I might add something about finitely generated groups, and in that case that should definitely be included.

Comment: @Babgen I am not completely sure what you mean by the second comment. I see that one gets a contradiction like in the abelian case, but I don't see it simplifying things (as it is tricky to determine which groups have a normal subgroups among the maximal subgroups).

Comment: I didn't know that students are not familiar such concepts. I mean: Let $G$  be a group with normal maximal subgroup $M_1$ and maximal subgroup $M_2$. Then $G=M_1M_2$.

Comment: @Babgen Ok, that was what I thought you meant. But I don't see how that really fits into the exercise.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend Theory of Groups by Rotman if you wanted a book with theory but since you want questions&answers Schaum's Outline of Group Theory.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is such a book. Yaglom's *Geometric Tansformations* is a classic text which basically makes you answer lots of questions as opposed to simply presenting the theory to you. The answers are at the back of the English version.

However, this text is not a classic group theory book. It is about one facet of group theory - isometries - rather than the theory as a whole.

Interesting point: it was translated into English from the original Russian as part of the "New Math" course in the United States, which was meant as a way of getting the maths level of the USA in line with that of Russia. So this is a school book. However, the Russians said that they would never, ever, under any circumstances, base a school course on this book. The problems in this book are not exactly easy...

Answer (score 1):

Well I guess you should read "Algebra by Artin".